# i need to make animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

my task is to make this effect on Scroll I am getting stuck this work on onClick but I need to set it on scroll if someone scrolls it effects work on top fade need to change onClick to onScroll and if you check the sandbox link you can see left side there are 5 headings when I click on first heading effect work but the issue is its call every data I need to set heading with data mean if I click on the first link only first link data appear not all if I click on the second link then only second link data appear

```
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.parent {
display: flex;
justify-content:space-evenly;
align-items: center;
}
.right{
  width: 60%;
  height: 10%;
}
.left {
  top: 150px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 56px;
}

.simple-trans-main > div {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 20%;
  
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring'
import './styles.css'

const pages = [
  ({ style }) => (
    <animated.div style={{ ...style,  }}>
      Robust, scalable and easily integrable Machine Learning based utility to crawl, scrape, parse and extract thousands of web indexes and text data from different sources in business ready format.
    </animated.div>
  ),
  ({ style }) => (
    <animated.div style={{ ...style, }}>
      NLP engine that can simplify text data problem in different languages to generate actionable insight/ outcome. Facilitates working on 50+ languages, runs analytics and eventual automated summarization of information/news   
    </animated.div>
  ),
  ({ style }) => (
    <animated.div style={{ ...style, }}>
      AI/ML based augmented data quality and validation engine tailored for industry practitioners working in specifics domains.
    </animated.div>
  ),
]
const pages2 = [
  ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightpink' }}>John Doe </animated.div>,
  ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightblue' }}>Jany</animated.div>,
  ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightgreen' }}>John Doe</animated.div>,
]
export default function App() {
  const [index, set] = useState(0)
  const onClick = useCallback(() => set((state) => (state + 1) % 3), [])
  const transitions = useTransition(index, (p) => p, {
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(75%,200%,0)' },
    enter: { opacity: 1, transform: 'translate3d(75%,0,0)' },
    leave: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(75%,-100%,0)' },
  })
  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <div className="left" onClick={onClick}>
      {/* {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => {
          const Page = pages2[item]
          return <Page key={key} style={props} />
        })} */}
        <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
            <h4><b>Squall - Data Parser</b></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
            <h4><b>Nimble - NLP Engine</b></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
            <h4><b>Penguin - Data Analyser</b></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
            <h4><b>Nimbus - Modelling Engine</b></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
            <h4><b>Triad - Auto Text Generation</b></h4>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div className="right simple-trans-main" onClick={onClick}>
        {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => {
          const Page = pages[item]
          return <Page key={key} style={props} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-silence-mvbcv?file=/src/index.js:0-2993)

Comment: "this animation" ??

Comment: @RiazLaskar what your doubt

Comment: Hey, I modified some `translate3d()`. Is this what you are looking for? https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-burnell-b7euv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: If you want animation to work on vertical axis, you need to modify a second value in `transform3d` property, not the first one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d()

Comment: but on scroll not on click

Comment: I have modified the code, to work onScroll. I have changed to `position:fixed;` in Styles.css so that card stays at center of Screen. I have also increased height of body to 150% to simulate scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const onScroll = useCallback(() => set((state) => (state + 1) % 3), [])
  const transitions = useTransition(index, (p) => p, {
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(75%,200%,0)' },
    enter: { opacity: 1, transform: 'translate3d(75%,0,0)' },
    leave: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(75%,-100%,0)' },
  })
window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false)
```

edit this link you you will git

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications to your code, check that out. [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-burnell-b7euv?file=/src/index.js). Changes

- Changed to `position:fixed;` in Styles.css so that card stays at
  center of Screen.
- I have also increased height of body to 150% to simulate scrolling.
- Added Event Listener for scroll (Changes card upon scrolling up/down)